# Remove HTTPS auto redirect

Tags: redirect, https

I changed the secure options on Configuration -> Web 'use secure in frontend' and 'use secure in adminhtml' to 'yes' but it was not configurated yet. I cannot access the admin pannel from a browser because it redirects automatically to a https.

I tried to change via database with the commands:

`UPDATE core_config_data
    SET value=0
    WHERE path='web/secure/use_in_frontend' OR path='web/secure/use_in_adminhtml' OR path='web/url/redirect_to_base';`

And deleted the var/cache but nothing happens.

**EDIT:**

`SELECT * FROM`core_config_data`WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/use_in_frontend';
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                       | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
|       327 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

`SELECT *  FROM`core_config_data`WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                        | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
|       328 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

But nothing had changed.

**EDIT 2:**

Some pages have a strange redirection pattern. For example: `http://www.mywebstore.com/customer/account/login/` sends me back to `http://www.mywebstore.com/`.

But `http://mywebstore.com/customer/account/login/`goes to `https://mywebstore.com/customer/account/login/` witch is a 'Not possible to access this webpage' page.

Comment: Might have multiple records in there ?

Comment: How can I check these?

Comment: Would you be using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: No. Only ssh terminal

Comment: select * from core_config_data where path like "web/secure/use_in%"

Comment: `mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like "web/secure/use_in%";

+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                        | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
|       327 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend  | 0     |
|       328 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+

2 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Could you clear your browser cache also please ?

Comment: Nothing happens :( keeps redirecting to https. Look: menu.com.vc click on top right side button "acesse sua conta"/access your account

Comment: check your secure path: change it back to http from https

Comment: It looks like these:

Comment: select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56244/discussion-between-rafael-miller-and-vaishal-patel).

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your core_config_data table in phpMyAdmin.
2. Find the row with the path web/secure/use_in_adminhtml and change its value field from 1 to 0 to enable accessing admin panel from unsecure http://www.yourwebsite.com/admin url

Changing **web/secure/use_in_frontend** toggles customer shopping cart security, 1=on and 0=off which probably isn't of importance as you're trying to regain administrative access

3. Clear **/var/cache, /var/session** and after you've done the above and regained access your system, reindex yourURL_rewrite index after changing settings. This is necessary because your config is cached and clearing it forces a reread of the configuration data from the core_config_data table.
   You should now be able to access your Magento Admin panel by standard unsecured web access **(**port 80, http)****.

**NOTE:** Be aware that accidentally entering your leading https:// instead of http:// on your unsecure_base_url before you have enabled TLS/SSL on your webserver will lock you out, so if the above doesn't get you in, look for rows with **web/unsecure/base_url** and check for the aforementioned misconfiguration

**EDIT:**

After doing all these things I still couldn't be able to access the admin pannel or any http page without redirecting to https page. So I did a backup from my database (via ssh) and from the folders and created another image from the website. When I moved everything from the old one to the new website, everything worked fine.

So... I really don't know what I did that really solved the problem, but I know one thing: **Do regular backups**.

Comment: nothing happens :(

Comment: I have just loaded your site and the page in question loads.

Comment: I did a backup from other version and uploaded everything. The error was never solved :( but thanks a lot Vaishal Patel!

Comment: Rafael at least you are back up and running

Comment: I have just do 2 and 3 steps an my admin is working in my magento 2.2.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking this SQL query:

```
select value from core_config_data WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_link_url', 'web/secure/base_link_url');
```

And see if there is any url with https, it helped me to fix similar issue